# Why is the Mississippi city not listed in iOS's world clock city list?

Tags: timezone, clock

Why can’t I find any cities for Mississippi in the iOS world clock.
Are there cities in other states that are being ignored？
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251741879?answerId=253343496022#253343496022

I searched by Google and asked chatGPT, there is no answer.
Although I used New Orleans instead to achieve the purpose, there are always some doubts.